# using the SSH key generated by ed25519 algorithm in git required password every time I pull or push

Tags: git, ssh, rsa, ed25519

I found that when using the SSH key which generated by ed25519 algorithm in github, I am required to input the password every time when pull or push;

but if I use the SSH key generated by rsa algorithm, everything is ok, not need password or ohther thing.

and I try in github and gitlab, I got the same situation：

the SSH key generated by ed25519 algorithm: What the hell are you? fill the password or go away!

the SSH key generated by rsa algorithm: Hello and welcome, I know who you are.

I set the config file in .ssh directory like:

[image: config 1]

and run `ssh -T git@github.com`, I got:

[image]

and I change the config file to:

[image: config 2]

run `ssh -T git@github.com` again, I got:

[image]

its really confused me.

by the way, the first key is ed25519, the second is rsa.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on MacOS, linux or windows?

If on MacOS, you might need to add additional fields in your `~/.ssh/config`

If so, add the try adding following lines below to save password in ssh-agent & os keychain.

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile /new/key/file
```

Comment: I am on MacOS, and my config file had set more than one host like github, personal gitlab, company gitlab, diffrent hosts are using diffrent key file; if i set AddKeysToAgent and UseKeychain to save github password, Will this affect others host I setting?

Comment: the `*` accounts for all, but you can change the host to whichever you'd like. Just add the two lines you don't have to your github host section.
`AddKeysToAgent yes`
`UseKeychain yes`

Also, I am unsure if you need the `PreferredAuthentication` field. Try without first and if not, try adding.

Comment: That's great, no problem! If you could, please mark the question as answered so it may help others in the future!

Answer (score 0):

When you make the ed25519 SSH key it gives you the option to enter the passphrase or says "empty for no passphrase".  Its kind of like 2 factor authentication, it still requires a password just in case its a shared machine/account or you want that layer of security.

Comment: damn it! so i should input my pwd when generate the key, right?